# perl pattern matching in multiline string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable that holds some 100 lines in it. I need to print the lines where there is a url.

```
$string = "this is just a test line 1
this is a test line 2
http://somelink1
this is line 4
http://link2
...
...
```

I need to print only the url links.

How to print all the lines matching pattern from $string. Tried the below code.

```
my $resu =~ /(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?/, $string;
print $resu;
```

Comment: Please show  what you have tried.

Comment: If you did not read all your input into a scalar in one long string, it would be a simple matter to loop over the input line by line and print the desired lines. This is a bit of an XY-problem.

Comment: Although it has been closed with a related but not duplicate question, I think the piece you are looking for in the regex is the flags: mgc (multi-line, global, don't reset the position). Then loop through the match in a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`/g` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to match multiple lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = <<'END_STR';
this is just a test line 1
this is a test line 2
http://somelink1
this is line 4
http://link2
...
...
END_STR

while ($string =~ m{(.*http://.*)}g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
http://somelink1
http://link2
```

However, if you're pulling in this data from a file, you'd be better off just doing line by line file reading:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    print if m{(.*http://.*)}g;
}
```